# How transform a php multidimensional array into a new array using the first column as key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, remap

I'm trying to use an array function (I thought about `array_map()` or `array_walk()`, but couldn't get it to do what I want) in order to create an array using a multidimensional array (Like a MySQL result) turning a field from the array into the key of the new one.

Say I have an array like this one:

```
$a = array(
    0 => array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'john' ), 
    1 => array( 'id' => 28, 'name' => 'peter' )
);
```

And I'd like to get another array like this:

```
$b = array(
    1 => array( 'name' => 'john' ), 
    28 => array( 'name' => 'peter' )
);
```

I can solve it with a simple foreach loop, but I wonder whether there's a more efficient way, using a built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_map` and `array_walk` don't allow you to change keys. A foreach loop is definitely the way to go. Foreach can even be more efficient than array_walk/array_map a lot of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use array_column function The Output its close to what you want

```
array_column($a, null, 'id')
```

Comment: To clarify for researchers, this answer will apply `id ` values as first level keys without changing the associative data within each row.  (It does not provide the desired result in the asked question.)

Answer (score 0):

This task can actually be done with a "body-less" `foreach()` loop.

Using "array destructuing" to define variables and square-brace pushing syntax, the entire operation can be written in the `foreach()` signature.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QD4qD))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($a as ['id' => $id, 'name' => $result[$id]['name']]);

var_export($result);
```

---

If a functional approach is preferred, then `array_reduce()` is capable of writing first level keys to the output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Eq5rX))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $a,
        fn($result, $row) => array_replace($result, [$row['id'] => ['name' => $row['name']]]), 
        []
    )
);
```